# Swift Image clicked Button not changing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button which is supposed to change image when it is clicked but for some reason it is not changing to the image set for the UIControlState.Highlighted state

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let versusButtonClickedImage = UIImage(named: "versus_button_cicked") as UIImage
    let versusButtonImage = UIImage(named: "versus_button") as UIImage
    versusButton.setImage( versusButtonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)


    versusButton.setImage(versusButtonClickedImage, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)


}
```

Comment: There is no need for those two `as UIImage` parts.

Comment: the Image should have extension, the only name doesn't retrieve the image.  `UIImage(named: "versus_button.png")`

Comment: For normal state the image is there or not?

Answer (score 9):

You  have to add extension of image.
 
And no need to create separate variables of image.

```
testBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"a1.png"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)
testBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"a2.png"),forState:UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, the problem might be with the image name, you might need to be provide with their extension as well :
Instead of

```
 let versusButtonClickedImage = UIImage(named: "versus_button_cicked") as UIImage
```

Use

```
let versusButtonClickedImage = UIImage(named: "versus_button_cicked.png") as UIImage
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, (at least as of today, December 2014), you need to provide the image name INCLUDING extension to `UIImage(named:)` for it to work.
As far as I know, in Obj-C you don't have to.

Example:

```
self.CButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ArrowUp30.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

But this one does not work:

```
self.CButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ArrowUp30"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

The '`highlighted`' state means a finger press in the button and keep pressing (without leaving the screen). So if user 'tapped' (press then leave) the button. It would restore to the 'normal' state. You should set different images manually in the button's action method.

```
func buttonTapped() {
    let normalImage = self.button.imageForState(.Normal)
    let highlightedImage = self.button.imageForState(.Highlighted)
    button.setBackgroundImage(highlightedImage, forState: .Normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(normalImage, forState: .Highlighted)
}
```